# Jolt to Transform JSON Array

Tags: arrays, json, xml, transformation, jolt

I want to use Jolt to transform a JSON dataset. The problem is that my entire dataset is treated like an array because it is originally transformed from XML. Here is an example of the first 3 records:

```
{

    "XMLSOCCER.COM" : { "Team" :[{

    "Team_Id" : "45",
    "Name" : "Aberdeen",
    "Country" : "Scotland",
    "Stadium" : "Pittodrie Stadium",
    "HomePageURL" : "http://www.afc.co.uk",
    "WIKILink" : "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aberdeen_F.C.",
    "Capacity" : "20866",
    "Manager" : "Derek McInnes"
},{

    "Team_Id" : "46",
    "Name" : "St Johnstone",
    "Country" : "Scotland",
    "Stadium" : "McDiarmid Park",
    "HomePageURL" : "http://www.perthstjohnstonefc.co.uk",
    "WIKILink" : "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Johnstone_F.C."
},{

    "Team_Id" : "47",
    "Name" : "Motherwell",
    "Country" : "Scotland",
    "Stadium" : "Fir Park Stadium",
    "HomePageURL" : "http://www.motherwellfc.co.uk",
    "WIKILink" : "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motherwell_F.C."
}}]}}
```

For a single record-set, I can use this spec which gives me the correct output:

```
[
{
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "XMLSOCCER.COM": {
    "Team": {
      "Team_Id": "Team_Id",
      "Name": "Name",
      "Country": "Country",
      "Stadium": "Stadium",
      "Capacity": "Capacity",
      "Manager": "Manager"
    }
  }
}}]
```

But because my entire dataset is treated as a JSON array (an array under "Team"), I cannot figure out how to create the spec to work with this configuration. I appreciate any input. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Spec: Match into all the elements of the Team array, and then reference the element number of the team array for each key in the output.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "XMLSOCCER.COM": {
        "Team": {
          "*": {
            "Team_Id": "soccer[&1].Team_Id",
            "Name": "soccer[&1].Name",
            "Country": "soccer[&1].Country",
            "Stadium": "soccer[&1].Stadium",
            "Capacity": "soccer[&1].Capacity",
            "Manager": "soccer[&1].Manager"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```